# R - ggplot2 - Right interval option in geom_histogram

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

Having this data that ranges from 0.42 to 1:

```
> summary(performance$SPC8)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4210  0.7805  0.8590  0.8359  0.9220  1.0000
```

I did the following histogram:

```
ggplot(performance, aes(x=SPC8)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count.. /74)), binwidth=.1, colour="black", fill="cadetblue3") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(SPC8, na.rm=T)),color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  format_options
```

[image]
How can I change the code above so that no bin is after "1"?

Comment: @PGreen I wasn't talking to you and I agree that the answer completely solves this. In fact, I was compiling the same answer, but took too long to produce a reproducible example (which is actually your job when asking a question).

Comment: @Roland sorry I didn't see David Arenburg comments and I thought you were refering to my question. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`geom_histogram()` uses `stat_bin()` to divide your data in bins. Default value for `stat_bin()` is `right=FALSE` that means that class start with value including and end with value not including this value, for example, class 0.9-1 will include 0.9 but won't include 1. To change this to oposite direction just add `right=TRUE` to `geom_histogram()`.

```
 ggplot(performance, aes(x=SPC8)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count.. /74)), binwidth=.1, colour="black",
         fill="cadetblue3",right=TRUE) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(SPC8, na.rm=T)),color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```